# Amazon connect after SAML authentication, there is a cors errorwhile connecting CCp in custom application

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

After the Successful SAML authentication, we mapped to the application page, but using the connect stream, we could no initialise CCP in iframe.
We are getting error Refused to display http://instanceURL in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'same origin'.

We implemented SAML, We need to login with CCP successfully, We also have custom URL iP in the instance's approved Origins

Comment: It's most likely you didn't configure approved origins, or configured it wrong. Hard to tell without screenshots or concrete details.